# is SqlCipher for iOS is FIPS Compliant

Tags: ios, encryption, core-data, sqlcipher, fips

As SQLCipher uses CommonCrypto framework and CommonCrypto is FIPS compliant, so can we consider SqlCipher is FIPS complaint too.

If it's not FIPS complaint, any other option which we can use for database encryption and its FIPS complaint.

I have tried following two options

1. Using [EncryptedCoreData](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data)
2. Manual data encryption while saving and decryption while fetching from core data [Ref Tutorial](https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.com/2016/09/can-core-data-be-trusted-with-sensitive.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't consider or claim that SQLCipher is FIPS 140-2 validated in this circumstance. Please see this GitHub issue for a detailed discussion of the reasons:

https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/issues/189#issuecomment-332471040